# Where are CiviCRM's date preferences actually used?

Tags: localisation, dates

Under Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences, CiviCRM offers a number of date classes for which an administrator can specify date formats. *activityDate* is described as "Date for activities including contributions: receive, receipt, cancel. membership: join, start, renew. case: start, end." *activityDateTime* is described as "Date and time for activity: scheduled. participant: registered."

Where are these settings actually used? I changed the date format for both of these, cleared CiviCRM's caches, and headed over to the contact summary, expecting to see the new date formats on the Activities and Contributions tabs. Instead, I found no change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually (at least) two places where you can change the formats. One is where you described, the other one (that affects most of the displayed date formats e.g. in the contact tab) is available at >>Administer >>Localization >>Date formats.

Below is a screenshot of settings we usually use for German language environments.

[image: Date Settings German]

Comment: Marking my question as answered. Though it does not answer the explicit question of where those date formats are used, it does answer the implicit how-do-I question. Thanks!